# PyKivy: How would you make a signup input with a Email

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, pymysql

I'm trying to make an app where you have to sign up or login but I don't know how to make the textinput for the email. I want to make it so if you did not put a "@" then you will not be able to proceed to the next screen.

How could I do this?

My code:

```
email = emailText 
emailcheck = ("(%s@%s)")

        if email > 0 or email != (emailcheck):
            print("Email Taken")

        else:
            print("Email Avaliable")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if "@" not in emailCheck:
    #loop back through email input
```

I'm not sure if you wanted an explanation of how to loop as well since this is a very basic question, but if you do let me know and I can explain it.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I have another question, I hope you can help me with it. How would you change a screen within python code and not inside the kv file?

email = emailText 
emailcheck = ("(%s)")

        if email > 0 or "@" in emailcheck:
            print("Email Taken")

        else:
            print("Email Avaliable")
            Screentwo()

it doesnt change into that screen.

Comment: No problem. I don't usually work with Kivy so I don't think I'm the best person to help with that. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787525/kivy-changing-screen-from-python-code) deals with that but if that doesn't help you might be better off asking a new question. If my answer works for you please accept it. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! Im so sorry for spending your time like that. Im kinda new to kivy. And I couldn't find that post anywhere. I'll just have to try searching things up more harder. But it worked! Thank youu!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out something that may help you
This is the main .py File

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class Layout(FloatLayout):
    def CheckEmail(self):
        if '@' not in self.ids.passwd.text:
            print('Please enter a valid email')
        else:
            print('Email Registration Successful')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

And this is the .kv file for object distribution

```
<Layout>:
    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.6,"top":0.5}
        size_hint:0.1,0.05
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.CheckEmail()
    TextInput:
        id: passwd
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1, "top":0.5}
        size_hint: 0.5,0.05
        multiline: False
```

This will display a submition button and a textinput.
The main function is whenever you type an email address in the textinput it will check for "@" as requested by you.

I think this will help you.

> Make sure that you save the .kv file as my.kv.