# kivy switch_to screen on if statement doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, string, if-statement, kivy

I could REALLY use your help with this one.
I'm trying to make a sort-of voice command operated menu for a toddler's learning app and kivy is giving me a headache

all of my screens are correctly defined and load as intended if the buttons are pressed but the voice commands, even though they register correctly and carry over their variables as intended they don't seem to have the desired effect when asked to act upon ScreenManager when the if statement is fulfilled

```
        def on_enter(self):
        ....
        Command.start()
        Command.introMenu()
        ......
            if Command.sel == "shapes":
                ScreenManager().switch_to = "shapes"
            elif Command.sel == "colours":
                ScreenManager().switch_to = "colours"
            ......
            else:
                pass
```

the variable `Command.sel` is captured from a dependency, defined as a string and carried correctly as far as I can tell from the variables view in debugging

[image: variables]

yet even though everything seems to be in order (in fact no error messages appear at all) the desired screen is not called when the if condition is met

what am I doing wrong here???

full code [here](https://github.com/Giorgos-vr/Tina)
(please ignore the Greek bits in the code... it's just strings, imagine it's any other language for that matter...)

thank you!

Comment: Whenever you use `ScreenManager()`, you are creating a new instance of `ScreenManager`, that is unrelated to the `ScreenManager` in your `App`. You must access the actual instance of `ScreenManager` that is part of your `App`.

Comment: so @JohnAnderson instead of ```ScreenManager()``` I should be referring to the screenmanager class (in my case named ```WindowManager(ScreenManager)```)?

My app class is just a builder that loads Main.kv

```class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Main.kv')```

Comment: No, not the `ScreenManager` class, the actual instance of `ScreenManager` in your `App`. I can't tell you how to do that since you have not provided enough information.

Comment: Perhaps replacing `ScreenManager()` with `self.manager` might work.

Comment: I've linked the repo already
https://github.com/Giorgos-vr/Tina

please forgive my n00bness but I'm not sure to which part of it you are referring to exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved

correct command was

`self.parent.current = "your_screen_name"`

answer (eventually) found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787525/kivy-changing-screen-from-python-code)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).