# Don't understand how to change screen in python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have spent a reasonable amount of time struggling to understand how to change the screen in python since I had to move the kv builder inside the build(self) function. I have tried using self.parent.current, app.root.current, kv.current (Which is what used to work) and self.manager.current functions and followed other stack overflow solutions such as:

[Kivy: changing screen from python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787525/kivy-changing-screen-from-python-code)

However, I get to a stage with each of these where I either have the same problem or it does not work.
I am attempting to change to the same screen no matter which button is pressed in a for loop and am still fairly new to this. Any help would be appreciated

The line of code in question is marked as:#THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE TO THE SPECIFIC FIND WINDOW

I changed some code due to adding string properties and it has thus stopped working.

main.py:

```
***

> import pickle
from click import command
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from datetime import datetime, date
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.metrics import dp
from functools import partial
from settingsjson import settings_json

FindsFileName = "Finds.obj"

# Recipe for new find object created by instancing.
class NewFindBlueprint:
    def __init__(self, Name=None, Date=None, Time=None, GPS=None, Photos=None, Description=None, Depth=None, Soil_Conditions=None, Weather_Conditions=None) -> None:
        self.Name = Name
        self.Date = Date
        self.Time = Time
        self.GPS = GPS
        self.Photos = Photos
        self.Description = Description
        self.Depth = Depth
        self.Soil_Conditions = Soil_Conditions
        self.Weather_Conditions = Weather_Conditions

# The window on which the app is loaded, this can be used to help explain the purpose and use of the app.
class BaseWindow(Screen):
    pass

# The base screen used for inputting a new find into the collection [base information of GPS, photos, name, date and time, as well as ony other information desired].
class InFieldFindInputWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
    
    # Keep for reference
    #def HowToCollectDataFunction(self):
    #    print("val={0}".format(self.ids.NewFindName.text))

    def RefreshDateAndTime(self):
        pass

    def AddNewFind(self):
        NewFindName = self.ids.NewFindName.text
        Current_Time = datetime.now()
        Current_Time_HHMMSS = Current_Time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        Current_Date = date.today()
        Current_Date_DDMMYYYY=Current_Date.strftime("%d %B %y")
        NewFindDate = Current_Date_DDMMYYYY
        NewFindTime = Current_Time_HHMMSS
        NewFindGPS = "1"
        NewFindPhoto = "1"
        if False:
            NewFindDepth = self.ids.Depth.text
        NewFindObject = NewFindBlueprint(Name=NewFindName,Date=Current_Date_DDMMYYYY,Time=Current_Time_HHMMSS)
        print(NewFindObject.Name, NewFindObject.Date, NewFindObject.Time, NewFindObject.GPS)
        InputFileObject = open(FindsFileName,"ab")
        pickle.dump(NewFindObject,InputFileObject)
        InputFileObject.close()


# Show all of the finds in a steack layout window with scroll compatibility, no matter the state.
class ViewFindsWindow(Screen):
    pass
        
class AllFindsGridLayout(GridLayout):
    FindButton={} # Create dictionary, used for holding the ids!!
    FindInfoName = StringProperty("Name of Find")
    FindInfoDate = StringProperty("Date of Find")
    FindInfoTime = StringProperty("Time of Find")
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        BackButton = Button(text="Back",color=(1,1,0,1))
        BackButton.bind(on_release=self.BackToMainMenu)
        self.add_widget(BackButton)
        for Find in self.AllFinds:
                self.FindButton[Find.Name] = Button(text = Find.Name, size_hint_y=None,height=dp(100))
                self.add_widget(self.FindButton[Find.Name])
                self.FindButton[Find.Name].bind(on_release=partial(self.ViewSpecificFindInfo, Find.Name, Find.Date, Find.Time ))
    def LoadAllFinds(filename):
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            while True:
                try:
                    yield pickle.load(f)
                except EOFError:
                    break
        
    AllFinds = LoadAllFinds(FindsFileName)
    def ViewSpecificFindInfo(self,FindName,FindDate,FindTime,ObjectInfo):
        print(FindName,FindDate,FindTime)
        # First thing is code to change the info to display.
        App.get_running_app().FindInfoName = FindName
        App.get_running_app().FindInfoDate = FindDate
        App.get_running_app().FindInfoTime = FindTime
        # Secondly go to the screen to show the specific find.
        #THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE TO THE SPECIFIC FIND WINDOW
    
    # Return to Main Menu
    def BackToMainMenu(self,event):
        App.root_window="Base Window"      

# Shows only finds which have been entered in the field but not updated at home yet. Works based on a set of standard key conditions to qualify as updated.
class AtHomeUpdateFindsWindow(Screen):
    pass

# Shows the information of one specific find including images, 3D scans, name, gps coords, location in collection, etc.
class SpecificFindInfoWindow(Screen):
    FindInfoName = StringProperty("Name of Find")
    FindInfoDate = StringProperty("Date of Find")
    FindInfoTime = StringProperty("Time of Find")
    pass

# Allows to view all inputted permissions.
class PermissionsWindow(Screen):
    pass

# Enables the addition of a permission zone, including name, area, phone number, date and time.
class AddPermissionsWindow(Screen):
    pass

# Options window for disabling more opportunities.
class OptionsWindow(Screen):
    pass

###
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
###


# Designating the design .kv file
#kv = Builder.load_file('MetalDetectorsFriend.kv')

class MetalDetectorsFriendApp(App):
    FindInfoName = StringProperty("Name of Find")
    FindInfoDate = StringProperty("Date of Find")
    FindInfoTime = StringProperty("Time of Find")
    def build(self):
        pass #This loads the kv file as it must load before due to string properties

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('In Field Find Input',{
            'DepthBoolean':True,
            'GroundConditionBoolean':True,
            'WeatherConditionsBoolean':True
        })
    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('In Field Find Options',self.config,data=settings_json)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MetalDetectorsFriendApp().run()

***
```

MetalDetectorsFriend.kv

```
***

> WindowManager:
    BaseWindow:
    InFieldFindInputWindow:
    ViewFindsWindow:
    AtHomeUpdateFindsWindow:
    SpecificFindInfoWindow:
    PermissionsWindow:
    AddPermissionsWindow:
    OptionsWindow:

<BaseWindow>:
    name:"Base Window"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        Label:
            text:"Welcome to Metal Detectors Friend"
            font_size:16
        Button:
            text:"Add new find"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "In Field Find Input Window"
        Button:
            text:"View all finds"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "View Finds Window"
        Button:
            text:"Options"
            on_release:
                app.open_settings()
        Button:
            text:"test"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Specific Find Info Window"

<InFieldFindInputWindow>:
    name: "In Field Find Input Window"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            Button:
                id: IFFIWBackButton
                text: "Back"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Base Window"
                size_hint:0.1,1
            TextInput:
                id: NewFindName
                size_hint:0.9,1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            Label:
                text: "Photos"
            Label:
                text: "Map"
        Label:
            text:"GPS coordinates"
        TextInput:
            id: Depth
            disabled:True
        TextInput:
            id: SoilConditions
            disabled:True
        TextInput:
            id: WeatherConditions
            disabled:True
        Button:
            id: AddNewFindButton
            text: "Add find to collection"
            on_release: 
                root.AddNewFind()
            #    root.HowToCollectDataFunction() # Reference: How to use the function from Python
                #app.root.current = "View Finds Window"




<ViewFindsWindow>:
    name: "View Finds Window"
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x:False
        do_scroll_y:True
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint_y:None
            height:self.minimum_height
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"horizontal"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:"100dp"
                Button:
                    size_hint:0.2,1
                    text: "Back"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current="Base Window"
                Label:
                    text:"All Finds"
                    size_hint:0.8,1
            AllFindsGridLayout:
                cols: 2
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.minimum_height
        ##ScrollView:
        ##do_scroll_x:False
        ##do_scroll_y:True
        ##AllFindsGridLayout:
        ##    cols: 2
        ##    padding: 10
        ##    spacing: 10
        ##    size_hint_y:None
        ##    height:self.minimum_height

        #BoxLayout:
        #    orientation:"vertical"
        #    size_hint_y:None
        #    height:self.minimum_height
            #BoxLayout:
            #    orientation:"horizontal"
            #    Button:
            #        text:"Back"
            #        on_release:
            #            app.root.current = "Base Window"
            #        size_hint:0.2,1
            #    Label:
            #        text:"All Finds"
            #        size_hint: 0.8,1
            
                    
            


        
#TEST
<AtHomeUpdateFindsWindow>:
    name: "At Home Update Finds Window"

<SpecificFindInfoWindow>:
    name: "Specific Find Info Window"
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x:False
        do_scroll_y:True
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint:1, None
            height:self.minimum_height
            #Test this:::
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"horizontal"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:"50dp"
                Button:
                    on_release:app.root.current = "Base Window"
                    text:"Back"
                    size_hint_x:0.2
                Label:
                    text: "View specific find"
                    size_hint_x:0.8
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:"100dp"
                Label:
                    id: SpecificFindInfoName
                    text: app.FindInfoName
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"horizontal"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:"100dp"
                Label:
                    id: SpecificFindInfoDate
                    text:app.FindInfoDate
                Label:
                    id: SpecificFindInfoTime
                    text:app.FindInfoTime
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"horizontal"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:"400dp"
                Button:
                    text:"Photos"
                Button:
                    text:"Map"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:"400dp"
                Button:
                    text:"WAYYYY YEEAH"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:"400dp"
                Button:
                    text:"WAYYYY YEEAH"
            
            #####

<PermissionsWindow>:
    name: "Permissions Window"

<AddPermissionsWindow>:
    name: "Add Permissions Window"

<OptionsWindow>:
    name: "Options Window"
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint_y:None
            height:self.minimum_height
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"horizontal"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.minimum_height
                Button:
                    text:"Back"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "Base Window"
                    size_hint_x:0.2
                Label:
                    text:"In field input settings"
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"100dp"
                    size_hint_x:0.8
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.minimum_height
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"horizontal"
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"100dp"
                    Label:
                        text:"Depth enabled"
                    Switch:
                        id:Depth_Enabled
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"horizontal"
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"100dp"
                    Label:
                        text:"Soil conditions enabled"
                    Switch:
                        id:Soil_Conditions_Enabled
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"horizontal"
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"100dp"
                    Label:
                        text: "Weather Conditions enabled"
                    Switch:
                        id: Weather_Conditions_Enabled
```

---

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to use the `current` attribute of the `ScreenManager` and the `name` of the desired `Screen`. In your `ViewSpecificFindInfo()` method, just add:

```
App.get_running_app().root.current = "Specific Find Info Window"
```

This code get the current running `App`, then gets its `root` (which is `WindowManager`, in your code), and sets its `current` property to the name of the desired `Screen`.